# API Response in APP

Tags: rest

How can we capture the response from REST API.

Here is what I am doing:

1. React JS page which contains the button for login.
2. As soon as you click login it will redirect to Ping Identity Login page.
3. On login page user need to authenticate himself.
4. In case he is valid user Ping will redirect to REST API which is post internally and send the response back.
5. How can we capture the JSON response coming back in ReactJS.